# Evaluating whether an object is null in javascript

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

My action specifies, let's say, an email address:

```
private String email;
public String getEmail() {
  return email;
}
```

But sometimes, the action can just not fill in the email, keeping it null. How can I evaluate this scenario in jquery?
Something like this definitely did not help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (${email}) {
      //do something
    } else {
      //do another thing
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to quote strings in JavaScript.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the tip. GriffeyDog's answer did it.

Comment: Just a side note - adding quotes is all you need to do for this to work as the empty string will evaluate as false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript:

```
var myVar = "${email}";
if (myVar !== "") {
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the variable with `typeof`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: In this case, I cannot. When the email is `null`, the javascript on the client would be generated like `if (typeof()) {`